# Aspect doesn't work with annotation for some methods

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop, spring-aop

I have a problem with using Aspect with annotation. The aspect method is triggered in some methods, but not in some other methods. 
What I have checked is the methods are public, and the class it doesn't work is @Component.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class PrometheusCounterMetricAspect {

  private static final Map<String, Counter> counters = new HashMap<>();

  @Before(
      "execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(package.aspects.PrometheusCounterMetric)")
  void beforeInsert(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    .....}
```

This is annotation interface

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface PrometheusCounterMetric {
  String metricName();
}
```

And in the project the flow is controller -> service -> storage. It works in service, but not in storage, despite the fact that It is component.

Comment: Would you mind editing your question to become an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), e.g. add a class it works for and one in which it doesn't? Please don't forget package names in all your classes as those are relevant to Spring AOP. It is hard to reason about the differences in your service and storage classes if we cannot see them. The Spring configuration which wired the components or activates component scan would also be good to see.